# Which improvements can we expect in Quantum Error Correction?

Tags: error-correction, error-mitigation

According to [this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.11157.pdf):

> The surface code is currently the most widely pursued quantum error correction scheme

(Emphasis mine). It is also said:

> However, there are drawbacks to the surface code, most notably its poor encoding density

(Emphasis mine). One can also often read in the literature that around a thousand of physical qubits are required to produce a single logical qubit.

Is this the only improvement one can hope/expect concerning error correction? Is this improvement realistic, given that, if I'm not mistaken, surface codes have been around for a while? I know that some research groups on error correction/mitigation prefer to focus on the physical implementation of existing schemes rather than trying to develop a new, more efficient scheme. Does that mean that we probably reached the peak of what can be done in error correction/mitigation algorithmic-wise?

Comment: [See this article](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41567-021-01423-9) which is freshly new from this week. New schemes are always suggested. This one, for example, is dealing with distance=2 code, and post-selection of only the success algorithm run, and throw to garbage all the rest. Honestly, I did not understand the success of this case, because, in every logical qubit, there is a chance of 75% of failure. which is becoming very bad in high amount of qubits.